# Need help identifying a rotary switch component

Tags: switches, identification, surface-mount, rotary

I've tried all kinds of rotary encoders and rotary switches, but none seem to match this one exactly.

It is from an old car radio (many radios have them). When rotated, the current flows through one of the three bottom "pins". Inside there are three equally spaced "forks". Can you guys help me identify it so I can get a new one?

Maybe it is an SPDT rotary switch, but I haven't been able to find any similar components online.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just an observation for your further research, this looks to me like a [quadrature encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_encoder#Quadrature_outputs).

Comment: Currently the question has one close vote with the reason "Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete". Suggest you edit the question body to remove the bit about where to purchase the switch. Adding some dimensions might help in the identification.

Comment: It appears that the pattern on the PC board is a vital part of the switch.  The other parts are likely custom parts, and not available separately from the board.

Comment: @PeterBennett I don't think it is part of the PCB but the remainder of the disassembled encoder. However, I back up the opinion about the custom part.

Comment: @thebusybee: after a closer look, I agree that the circular contacts may be on a black plastic part, rather than directly on the PCB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a google image search for "rotary quadrature encoder" found an in-stock Panasonic [EVQ-VVD00203B](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Panasonic/EVQ-VVD00203B?qs=tfZGHB2PWd3U%2F4kR6m1kxw%3D%3D) on a distributor website:

[image]

The [datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/315/ATC0000CE22-531565.pdf) has the following picture which looks to match the *shape* shown in the pictures in the question:

[image]

And as @thebusybee suggested in a comment this is a quadrature encoder, based upon the following from the datasheet:

[image]

If the encoder on the PCB could be measured, that would help to see if a match for the above Panasonic encoder. If not, could serve as an example of a range to check for a match.